# JAVA Win Service with procrun and CDI/WELD

Tags: java, service, daemon, jboss-weld, jsvc

I'm creating an OS background service using procrun ([Apache JSVC](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html)). I want to use [WELD](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) as a container.

The application by itself (gradle run) works fine. I can see desired behaviour. But when I'm trying to run it as a Windows service, I can see following errors:

```
PS C:\Users\szdud\Documents\Projects\Java\logreader\build\windows-service> .\LogReader.exe //TS//LogReader start
System coudn't find path given.
Unable to create logger at ''
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netps/build/LogReaderService
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netps.build.LogReaderService
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[2018-03-03 23:42:11] [error] [13612] FindClass com/netps/build/LogReaderService failed
[2018-03-03 23:42:11] [error] [ 3724] Failed to start Java
[2018-03-03 23:42:11] [error] [ 3724] ServiceStart returned 4
[2018-03-03 23:42:11] [error] [ 3724] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 3 (Failed to run service as console application)

Failed to run service as console application
```

Looks like the WELD lost it's context and classpath location. But I can't figure it why and how to fix it.

Can you help me please?

If you want to see the code you can check it here:
 [https://github.com/sdudziak/logreader](https://github.com/sdudziak/logreader/tree/feature/unified-os-service-app-architecture)

EDIT:
 I've created a single JAR file under the Linux OS to check if this is only a Win problem. And it's not. I've received same issues while I'm running the `java -jar log-reader-all-1.0.jar`:

```
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.226][DEBUG][main] logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.230][INFO ][main] Version - WELD-000900: 3.0.3 (Final)
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.251][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-000030: Cannot load class using the ResourceLoader: org.jboss.jandex.Index
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.419][DEBUG][main] DefaultBeanArchiveScanner - Resolved bean archive reference: /var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/log-
reader-all-1.0.jar for URL: jar:file:/var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/log-reader-all-1.0.jar!/META-INF/beans.xml
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.420][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-000032: Processing bean archive reference: /var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/log-reader-all-1.0.jar
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.420][DEBUG][main] FileSystemBeanArchiveHandler - Handle path: /var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/log-reader-all-1.0.jar
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.420][DEBUG][main] FileSystemBeanArchiveHandler - Handle archive file: /var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/log-reader-all-1.0.jar
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.440][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-000039: Bean archive reference /var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/log-reader-all-1.0.jar handled by org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.File
SystemBeanArchiveHandler@528c868
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.443][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-ENV-000024: Archive isolation enabled - creating multiple isolated bean archives if needed
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.446][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.446][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap > startContainer 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.454][DEBUG][main] Configuration - WELD-001902: Following configuration was detected and applied: {org.jboss.weld.executor.threadPoolType=COMMON, org.jboss.weld.construction.relaxed=true, org.j
boss.weld.bootstrap.allowOptimizedCleanup=true}
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.455][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap > startContainer > initServices 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.475][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - Using Weld modules: []
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.496][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - Using instantiator: org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.UnsafeProxyInstantiator
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.510][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker -   END bootstrap > startContainer > initServices (55 ms)
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.510][INFO ][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.537][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap > startContainer > builtinContexts 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.591][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%ApplicationContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.594][DEBUG][main] Reflection - WELD-000601: interface javax.inject.Singleton is missing @Target. Weld will use this annotation, however this may make the application unportable.
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.595][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%SingletonContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.597][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%BoundSessionContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.599][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%BoundConversationContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.600][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%BoundRequestContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.600][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%RequestContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.602][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%deployment%DependentContext
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.602][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker -   END bootstrap > startContainer > builtinContexts (64 ms)
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.605][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap > startContainer > readDeploymentStructure 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.621][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager] with qualifiers [@Default]
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.621][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl] with qualifiers [@Default]
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.622][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker -   END bootstrap > startContainer > readDeploymentStructure (16 ms)
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.622][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker -   END bootstrap > startContainer (176 ms)
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.623][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap > startInitialization 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.652][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; n/a
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.652][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000168: Extension bean deployed: Extension [class org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; n/a
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.665][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant] with qualifiers [@Default]; jar:file:/var/www/netps/logreader/build/libs/l
og-reader-all-1.0.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension@1[org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant@2cab9998]
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.665][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000168: Extension bean deployed: Extension [class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant] with qualifiers [@Default]; jar:file:/var/www/netps/log
reader/build/libs/log-reader-all-1.0.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension@1[org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant@2cab9998]
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.665][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager] with qualifiers [@Default]
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.665][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl] with qualifiers [@Default]
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.666][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker - START bootstrap > startInitialization > BeforeBeanDiscovery 
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.695][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000162: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType() called by org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldExtension@d78795 for [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Vetoed @Interceptor 
@ActivateRequestContext @Priority class org.jboss.weld.contexts.activator.ActivateRequestContextInterceptor
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.697][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000162: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType() called by org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldExtension@d78795 for [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Vetoed @Interceptor 
@ActivateRequestContext @Priority class org.jboss.weld.contexts.activator.CdiRequestContextActivatorInterceptor
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.701][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000162: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType() called by org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant@2cab9998 for [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Vetoed
 @ApplicationScoped class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.beans.ParametersFactory
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.704][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000162: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType() called by org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant@2cab9998 for [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Decora
tor class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.threading.RunnableDecorator
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.706][DEBUG][main] Bootstrap - WELD-000162: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType() called by org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant@2cab9998 for [BackedAnnotatedType] public @Vetoed
 @Interceptor @ActivateThreadScope @Priority class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.contexts.activators.ActivateThreadScopeInterceptor
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.706][DEBUG][main] BootstrapTracker -   END bootstrap > startInitialization > BeforeBeanDiscovery (40 ms)
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.799][INFO ][ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15] Bootstrap - WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from org.jboss.weld.servlet.api.helpers.ForwardingServletListener because of underly
ing class loading error: Type javax.servlet.ServletContextListener not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
[2018-03-05 10:52:10.800][DEBUG][ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15] Bootstrap - Catching
org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.WeldResourceLoader.classForName(WeldResourceLoader.java:44) ~[log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadClass(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:82) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:62) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:87) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:55) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:52) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55) [log-reader-all-1.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:283) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1603) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) [?:?]
```

It looks like it is not OS related issue, but something more on the line between gradle-weld: just like @siliarus wrote.

Comment: Doesn't look like a Weld problem, it's more about what Gradle does for you behind the scenes and what the Win service execution doesn't? Like putting stuff on classpath, or even module path? It looks like you are using Java 9, try running this on Java 8 just to make sure you eliminate module weirdness (which may possible cause this if, say, Gradle uses unnamed module for you automatically).

Comment: @Siliarus I've updated the question  to provide you an answer

Comment: @Siliarus checked the Java 8 (win10)- same issues :/; both for jar and for system service

Comment: Unless you are creating an uber jar, I would say you need to also specify classpath elements when executing this from command line. I suggest you inspect the *exact* command executed by Gradle. I suppose it has some debug output option much like Maven does. There you should see what it actually invokes.

Comment: I've created an uber jar, it gave me the same result. Lot of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError errors. - just like in the main topic. NVM, I'll check the exact command from gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

So the problem here is with the JAR hell, not only with WELD. 
What I will do is I will start the project from scratch, and I will create uber JAR each time I will add anything dependent to the project. This will show me which part is most problematic, and allows me to track issues more precisely.